# Change element in arraylist to true from user input

Tags: java

```
package issue;
import java.util.*;


public class Issue {

    private static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();



    public static ArrayList<Object> getArrayStringList(){
        for (Object o : list)
            System.out.println("["+o+"]");
        return list;
    }

    public static void removeIssue(){
        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){;
            System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
        }
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which one would you like to mark as solved?");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();

       ##This is where my problem is ##
        Object issue = list.get(choice);
        issue
    }

    public static void addIssue(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text= scan.nextLine();
        newIssue issue = new newIssue(text);
        list.add(issue);
    }
}
```

I want the user input to choose the appropriate element in the ArrayList and then set it to true using the `newIssue` class. But I can't figure out how to

```
package issue;

public class newIssue {

    public String issueText;
    public boolean returned = false;

    public newIssue(String issueText){
        this.issueText = issueText;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return issueText + returned;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Why is there written `issue` alone, after `Object issue = list.get(choice);` ?

Comment: Note that access to `static` variables should be indicated by writing the class name before: `Issue.list.get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(list.size() > 0 && choice <= list.size()-1) {
    newIssue issue = (newIssue)list.get(choice);
    issue.returned = true;
    System.out.println("newIssue = "+ issue.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list as:

```
private static ArrayList<newIssue> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can do:

```
newIssue issue = list.get(choice);
issue.returned = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, do you know how I can loop through an arraylist and only print out the objects with bool = true?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it depending on which Java version you are using. If you are using Java 8 or higher you can use Java steams and `filter` function. You can also use just a plain loop or `list.forEach`. There are many examples on how to do this on the Internet.